# gcc undefined reference when I know the references are correct

Tags: c, gcc, archlinux

I have this trivial C program, but just can't it to link correctly.

here is the program,

```
#include <gsl/gsl_cdf.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   double bottom_tail = gsl_cdf_gaussian_P(-1.96, 1);
   printf("Area between [-1.96, 1.96]: %g\n", 1-2*bottom_tail);
}
```

at the shell, I'm doing:

```
gcc gsl_erf.c -o gslTest -I/usr/local/include/gsl -L/usr/local/lib
```

I know for sure that the `gsl_cdf.h` header file is in `/usr/local/include/gsl`, similarly I know that the `.so`s are in `/usr/local/lib`

the linker, gcc backend?, complains that I have an undefined reference to `gsl_cdf_gaussian_P`

I thought my order was incorrect, so I also tried:

`gcc -I/usr/local/include/gsl -L/usr/local/lib gsl_erf.c -o gslTest`

but this craps out as well. What am I doing wrong? :(

Comment: Your question says that the undefined reference is `gel_cdf_gausssian_P`.  Is that a typo in the question, or does the linker message actually refer to "gel" rather than "gsl"?

Comment: no, that was a typo, fixed.

Comment: gsl_cdf_gau**sss**ian_P?

Comment: Ha, I didn't even notice that part.  :-)

Comment: okay, i think i got all the typos now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell the compiler to actually link with the library you're using:  you need an `-l` option, probably something like `-lgsl`.  (Take the name of the `.so` file, remove the `.so` suffix and `lib` prefix, and that's what to put after `-l`.)

The `-L` option tells the linker where to *find* libraries, but doesn't direct it to actually link with anything — just like the `-I` option tells the compiler where to find headers, but doesn't actually `#include` any code.

Comment: thanks, but now I get way more undefined references, all sorts of cblas_<something>. But I think this might be because I don't have blas installed. EDIT: Just installed blas but still have these undefined references. EDIT #2: Just looked on gnu page for gls, and found this, `The library is easy to compile and does not have any dependencies on other packages.` So i don't think it should matter if I don't have blas installed.

Comment: Looks like you also need `-lgslcblas`.  It comes with GSL (at least it did in the Debian package I just tried).  I'm not really familiar with GSL, but from the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/BLAS-Support.html) it sounds like they put the CBLAS stuff in a separate library so that you have the option of linking a different BLAS implementation instead.

Comment: okay, so I now did `gcc -I/usr/local/include/gsl -L/usr/local/lib gel_erf.c -o gslTest -lgsl -lgslcblas` and this compiled, but when running the executable, I get an error about loading the shared library, `libgsl.so.0` which I know exists in `/usr/local/lib/`

Comment: Sounds like `/usr/local/lib` isn't on the dynamic linker's search path, though I'm surprised if that's the case since most systems have it there by default.  Try setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib` when running the program.

Comment: Arch has a [GSL package](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/gsl/).  If you install that, you'll have the files in `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib` so you won't need the `-I`, `-L`, and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  (Plus you get all the other benefits of packages, like automated upgrades.)

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually ask for the libraries on the compile command. You provide a search path with "-L" but you don't actually request the libraries. You need something like "-lgsl" as well (assuming the library is libgsl.so).